# I would like to give value to a field with values ​from a field in another table

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I have two data extension, in the first one I have an empty field called codigo, to which I would like to give values ​​that are stored in the second data extension in the IdCodigo field, with the only condition that its status is false.

I have tried several things like an update with objective data extension 1, but I get nothing.

DE1[image]

DE2[image]

Any ideas to continue. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? We can build on that to help..

Comment: With this filter to know that the code field of DE1 is empty and can receive data from DE2 
SELECT CartId, Email, IsAbandoned, FirstName, Destination, Codigo, CreatedDate
FROM AR_SE_ABANDONED_CART_TEST
WHERE CreatedDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND (Email IS NOT NULL
OR Email != '')
AND (Codigo IS NULL
or Codigo = '')
order by newid()


The problem is that I don't know how I can pass the ID code data of the DE2 to the Code field of the DE1, with the proviso that the state is false to use

Comment: what is connecting DE1 to DE2? Email Address? Can you further explain what you are looking for, as it is, I cannot tell if you want to fill this with ALL values or specific to a foreign key, etc.

Comment: @Gortonington What I would like is to be able to pass the data in the code Id column of the DE2 to the code field of the DE1 randomly. Thank you